# Getting exception while searching for element in webtable

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I was trying to find element in webtable.

I am unable to fail a test when an element is not found

I have written code like this

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    String s = "16";
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@cellpadding='10' and @border='1']/descendant::tr"));
    int rowSize = list.size();
    System.out.println("rowsize " + rowSize);
    String xpath2 = "//table[@cellpadding='10' and @border='1']/child::tbody/child::tr[1]/child::td";
    List<WebElement> list2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath2));
    int colSize = list2.size();

    try {
        for (int x = 1; x < rowSize; x++) {
            //x += 1;
            for (int y = 1; y < colSize; y++) {
                //y += 1;
                String xpath = "//table[@cellpadding='10' and @border='1']/child::tbody/child::tr[" + x + "]/child::td[" + y + "][contains(.,'" + s + "')]";
                WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
                if (!we.getText().equals(s))
                    throw new ExplicitAssertionError("element not found");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("element not found");
    }
}
```

I am getting `NoSuchElementException`

Thanks for your time

Comment: do you not understand how `for` loops work?  why re-increment `x` and `y`?

Comment: because there is no element at tr[0] it is at tr[1]

Comment: so use `for (int x=1; x<rowSize; x++){`

Comment: Can you please share your html code snippet?

Comment: <h4>
Test Table</h4>
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
<tbody><tr>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>12</td>
  <td>13</td>
<td>14</td>
<td>15</td>
<td>16</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>21</td>
  <td>22</td>
  <td>23</td>
<td>24.63</td>
<td>25</td>
<td>26</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>31</td>
  <td>32</td>
  <td>33</td>
<td>34</td>
<td>35</td>
<td><form>
        <input id="submitButton" type="submit">
        <div id="timeLeft">Ready!</div>
</form>
</td></tr>
</tbody></table>